# Update O365 User Password Using Microsoft-Graph API

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

As part of a multitenant Application, I need to update the O365 user's password using:

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}?api-version
```

On the test environment, the update is working correctly, but in the production environment, I am not able to update the user's password.

There are separate Applications registered in the test and production Azure tenants but have the identical set of Application and Delegated permissions (both Windows Azure Active Directory and Microsoft Graph)

In O365 "Audit log Search" I can see the password reset activity in both test and production environment.

Do you have any suggestion what can cause this issue?

Comment: Is your `production` environment a federated one - i.e. the users are synchronised with on-premises AD?

Comment: No, there is no synchronisation in place in any of the environments. All the users in both cases are Azure AD users.